# Copy image location in vimperator

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-addons, context-menu, vimperator

When using [vimperator](http://vimperator.org/trac/wiki/Vimperator), how do I do the equivalent of right-clicking an image and clicking "copy image location"?

Comment: I believe that the mouse functions normally with vimperator.  If it's urgent, you could probably just save the image the normal way, although I'm looking into how to do it with their commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning, I didn't try this, because I'm at work. This is the theory from what I read online**

Download this file

[imageextender.js](http://svn.coderepos.org/share/lang/javascript/vimperator-plugins/trunk/imageextender.js)

and put it in

```
~/.vimperator/plugin/ (UNIX/LINUX)
```

or in

```
%HOME%\vimperator\plugin (Windows)
```

Usage (this is directly from the javascript source code):

> == USAGE ==
>   Extended-hints mode ';m' to yank image URL and ';M' to save image are
>   available. These are default settings. You can change these by below
>   settings.
>
> Ex-command ':downimageall' is also available. This is to download all
>   images of current page, but it effects heavy load to the server, you must
>   use carefully. We are NOT RESPONSIBLE for result of this command.
>
> Additionally, following modes are available if you installed Image Zoom
>   add-on ( https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/139 ). These feature
>   were provided by Frank Blendinger. Thanks !!
>
> - ';i' to zoom in image
> - ';x' to zoom out image
> - ';X' to zoom reset image
> - ';z' to zoom fit image
> - ';Z' to custom zoom image

[Here](http://vimperator.org/trac/wiki/Vimperator/Scripts) are the official install instructions on the vimperator site. There are more plugins listed there, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
;Iyd
```

Fire up `hints` for opening images in a new tab (`;I`), then yank (copy) the URL of the image while in the new tab (`y`), and then close the tab (`d`).

Also, you can always do:

```
;c
```

Which will start `hints` in `context menu` mode, meaning, once you press a number to identify an element, vimperator will open a `context menu` for that element, as if you right clicked in the element.

Comment: `;IyD` with uppercase `D` is slightly better in general as it maintains the current tab.